# belongstoMany relatioship returning empty array, but tinker shows data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use a **belongsToMany** relation, i never had any problems with it but for some reason it returns empty now.

But, if i check with **tinker**, i get array with data in it returned

I've set up my relation in the User model like this:

```
// linking with table tag
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','tag_user','user_id','tag_id');
}
```

**Tag model:**

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','tag_user','tag_id','user_id');
}
```

**PostController**

```
public function create()
{
    // bringing user details to show his preferneces
    $user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
    $user = User::find($user_id)->first();

    //post_types
    $types= PostType::pluck('name', 'post_type_id');

    return view('user.create_post')->with('user', $user)->with('types',$types);
}
```

**In view:**

```
@foreach ($user->tags as $tag)

           <label class = "btn btncategory">
                  <input type = "checkbox"
                         name = "tag_selected[]"
                         value = "{{$tag->tag_id}}" >
                   {{$tag->tag_name}}
           </label>
@endforeach
```

**Migrations**

**tags**

```
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('tag_id');
            $table->string('tag_name')->unique();
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->integer('used_time')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('tag_user', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('tag_id');
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'tag_id']);
        });
```

**users**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('user_name')->unique();
        $table->string('fname')->nullable();
        $table->string('lname')->nullable();
       ... etc etc
```

Comment: You definition is okay as it seems. Have you checked in the database for the same user that it returns empty if you have any records?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and literally saw an empty array or do you only have no inputs where inputs should be? 
Just to be sure.. Did you check that the user really has attached tags?

Comment: Please post the migrations of the three tables involved.

Comment: @nakov i checked, everything is there.. Even it was working before, suddenly stopped yesterday

Comment: @TimSch yes, i dumped the variable, it gave me empty array

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir added

Comment: I meant the *content* of the migration files: `Schema::create(...)`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir done

Comment: Did you set `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';` in the `User` model? And the same for `tag_id` in the `Tag` model?

Comment: yes i did that.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.6 is the version

Comment: Please log the executed query: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $user->tags; dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`